# What's the difference between spark-shell and spark-sql? Any performance differences?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

`Spark-shell`: which basically opens the `scala>` prompt. Where query needs to write in below manner

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
// Queries are expressed in HiveQL
sqlContext.sql("FROM src SELECT key, value").collect().foreach(println)
```

`spark-sql`: Which seems to connect directly to hive metastore and we can write a query in a similar way to hive. And query over existing data in hive

I want to know the difference between these two.. And does processing any query in **spark-sql** is same as in **spark-shell**? I mean can we leverage the performance benefits of spark in **spark-sql**?

Spark 1.5.2's here.

Comment: Ehm, spark-shell is just a shell. spark-sql on the other hand is a library. Comparing them is like comparing apples with tomatoes. BTW, spark-shell automatically imports different spark libraries and instantiate the `sqlContext` so you don't need this line `val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`spark-shell` gives you a working Spark environment where Scala is the (programming) language.

`spark-sql` gives you a Spark SQL environment where SQL is the query language.

Note that `spark-shell` is for any APIs available in Spark while `spark-sql` is only for Spark SQL API (with Datasets and DataFrames).

They're simply different interfaces for users with different skills (`spark-shell` for Spark/Scala developers while `spark-sql` for SQL developers).

`spark-sql` "hides" the Spark infrastructure behind SQL interface which places it higher in how much engineering skills one should have, but eventually uses all the optimizations available in Spark SQL (and Spark in general).

Performance-wise `spark-sql` and `spark-shell` are alike.

Comment: Thanks...one more thing which I noticed in sparksql is if I tired to join two 11million record tables, its quickly giving outofmemory error..so is there anyways to control the memory options in sparkSql

Comment: Sure. It's a Spark application after all so the common properties apply here --> http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Comment: @JacekLaskowski can we connect spark-sql to pyspark/spark-shell and import the tables as dataframes ?

Comment: @etl_devs Not sure I understand. Could you ask a separate question on SO if you can't find any similar ones?